# sqlite in windows phone 8 runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I trying to make a sample sqlite db app in windows phone 8 using [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/59b9d6/sqlite-for-windows-phone-app/).

now i am not able to add sqlite.dll in project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try deleting that reference and adding a new reference of Sqlite phone. The error is usually shown when you have a reference of an old sqlite version while you have updated the SQlite to a recent newer version

Comment: tried 10 times...nothing helped

Comment: have you added SQlite-net nuget package? Also you need to try the 4th step of your example and select the dll of the newly installed sqlite not the old one

Comment: nothing is shown in my package manager. where are these packages saved.?

Comment: Go to your Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects or the location where your solution file is after addition of nuget package you will find a Packages folder inside it you will find your installed packages.

Comment: Please follow this link, [Sqlite exception][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160873/exception-when-using-sqlite-in-winrt-app