# Having problems porting SQLite3-WinRT to windows 10 ARM devices

Tags: javascript, cordova, sqlite, winjs, windows-10-universal

Been trying to port the [SQLite3-WinRT component](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT) from windows 8.1 to work on windows 10. I have managed to get it working on for x64 and x86 architect. however when trying to deploy my app to a windows 10 ARM device it was crashing and reporting that 
"The specified module could not be found."
when I try to call SQLite3.openAsync

I tried the following resolutions and had no joy

[Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3' in SQLite Net Platform WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042772/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-in-sqlite-net-platform-winrt)

[Exception when using SQLite in WinRT app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160873/exception-when-using-sqlite-in-winrt-app)

[Windows 10 Universal Javascript app SQLite in Windows Mobile 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032927/windows-10-universal-javascript-app-sqlite-in-windows-mobile-10)

also used this guide to try resolve the issue by installing SQLite for windows universal from the extensions
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3
using the latest version of the SQLite3-WinRT component
using cordova 6.3.0
the device i'm deploying to is a windows 10 mobile Nokia Lumia 550

anyone able to shed some light on possible resolution ?

Comment: Could you share a demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: uploaded example demo here https://github.com/hsm22/SQLite3_ARM_Example

Answer (score 0):

Try using this component perhaps:


https://github.com/cloudcrypt/SQLite-Universal-WinJS-Component


It works as a SQLite Universal WinJS Component for Javascript Windows Store Apps running on the Windows 10 Universal App Platform.